# In Arabic what is the difference in the usage of the perfect tense negative and imperfect tense jussive.(as their translation is same in English.)

Tags: grammar, morphology, arabic

For eg : لَمْ يَكْتُبْ and مَا کَتَبَ both means "he did not write."
So how would I know which one i should use?

Comment: I recently read a source that claimed that in the Qur'an, مَا with the past tense (or perfect) is slightly more emphatic than لَمۡ with the jussive.  A little like saying "he did NOT write", as opposed to "he didn't write".  Unfortunately, the source didn't offer a whole lot of evidence - but maybe this is a direction to explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Classical Arabic there does not seem to be any difference in usage between maa + perfect and lam + jussive. In modern Arabic dialects only the former has survived. For this reason modern authors tend to avoid the form with maa in the mistaken belief that this is non-classical, or at least to treat the form with lam as belonging to the more formal register.